# PHP to CSV: Exporting certain fields only

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I am trying to grab some Gravity Forms entries and only export certain data from them to CSV.

I can echo out to screen during testing and I can also export to CSV the static test data (stored in the $contents array) you see below. But I am stuck trying to export the certain fields that I only need to export.

```
// How do I get this info into the CSV??
/*foreach ( $entries as $entry ) :  
    echo $entry['2'];
    echo $entry['3'];
    echo $entry['6'];
endforeach;*/

$csv_headers = [
    'Organisation Name',
    'Registered Charity Number',
    'Address',
    'Phone',
];

$contents = [
  [2014, 6, '1st half', 'roland@fsjinvestor.com', 0, 0],
  [2014, 6, '1st half', 'steve@neocodesoftware.com', 0, 0],
  [2014, 6, '1st half', 'susanne@casamanager.com', 0, 0],
  [2014, 6, '1st half', 'tim', 0, 0]
];

fputcsv($output_handle, $csv_headers);

foreach ( $contents as $content) :
    fputcsv($output_handle, $content);
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new array with elements of `$content`:

```
foreach ( $contents as $content) :
    fputcsv($output_handle, [$content[2], $content[3], $content[6]]);
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a new array based on the old one where you push only fields you want to show